# ASP.NET Core 5 MVC Using View Models with enumeration

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, viewmodel, asp.net-core-5.0

I have 2 models; `TypeOne` and `Project_Screen`. I need a view that makes 2 tables with information from both of those tables. I tried to use this guide to making a view model which helped but isnt doing quite the same thing I am: https://dotnettutorials.net/lesson/view-model-asp-net-core-mvc/

This is the View Model I made:

```
 public class MyProjectsViewModel
    {
        public Project_Screen Project_Screen { get; set; }
        public TypeOne TypeOne { get; set; }
    }
```

This is the controller:

```
 public class ProfileController : Controller
    {
        private readonly Natural_ResourcesContext _context;

        public ProfileController(Natural_ResourcesContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }
        // GET: Profile
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            Project_Screen project_Screen = (Project_Screen)(from s in _context.Project_Screen
                                                            where s.DSN_PM == User.Identity.Name
                                                            select s);
            TypeOne typeOne = (TypeOne)(from x in _context.TypeOne
                                        where x.Name == User.Identity.Name
                                        select x);
            MyProjectsViewModel myProjectsViewModel = new MyProjectsViewModel()
            {
                Project_Screen = project_Screen,
                TypeOne = typeOne
            };

            return View(myProjectsViewModel);
        }
    }
```

As you can see, `project_Screen` and `typeOne` are all records in which `Manager = Name`.

Then in the view I'd like to display these something like this:

```
@model EnvApp.ViewModels.MyProjectsViewModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Projects";
}

<h1>My Projects</h1>
<hr />
<h4>Screening Forms</h4>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                State Project Number
            </th>
            <th>
                Federal Project Number
            </th>
            <th>
                Project Name
            </th>
            <th>
                County
            </th>
            <th>
                Coordinates
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.State_Project_Number)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Federal_Project_Number)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Project_Name)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.County)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Coordinates)
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.ID">Details</a> 
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>

<br />
<hr />

<h4>Type One Projects</h4>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                State Project Number
            </th>
            <th>
                Federal Project Number
            </th>
            <th>
                Project Name
            </th>
            <th>
                County
            </th>
            <th>
                Coordinates
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.State_Project_Number)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Federal_Project_Number)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Project_Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.County)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Coordinates)
            </td>
            <td>
                <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.ID">Details</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I get the compiler error CS1579 on ````Model```:

```
foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'MyProjectsViewModel' because 'MyProjectsViewModel' does not contain a public instance or extension definition for 'GetEnumorator'
```

Which I think makes sense, because I have not denoted `Project_Screen` or `TypeOne` as an object that holds multiple records, but I'm not quite sure how to do this.

Am I on the right track or have I misunderstood this? What am I missing?

EDIT 1:

I did exactly what Md Farid Uddin Kiron said so the code in his answer reflects my view model and view. However I am still having issues with my controller.

```
  using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using EnvApp.ViewModels;
using EnvApp.Models.DB;

namespace EnvApp.Controllers
{
    public class ProfileController : Controller
    {
        private readonly Natural_ResourcesContext _context;

        public ProfileController(Natural_ResourcesContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }
        // GET: Profile
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            Project_Screen project_Screen = (Project_Screen)(from s in _context.Project_Screen
                                                            where s.DSN_PM == User.Identity.Name
                                                            select s);
            TypeOne typeOne = (TypeOne)(from x in _context.TypeOne
                                        where x.Name == User.Identity.Name
                                        select x);
            MyProjectsViewModel myProjectsViewModel = new MyProjectsViewModel()
            {
                Project_Screen = project_Screen,
                TypeOne = typeOne
            };

            return View(myProjectsViewModel);
        }
    }
}
```

The issue is that `project_Screen` and `typeOne` aren't lists or IEnumerable types, which makes sense, but I'm not the syntax to get them to be enumerable.

IF you need to see it, here is my view model:

```
public class MyProjectsViewModel
    {
        public List<Project_Screen> Project_Screen { get; set; }
        public List<TypeOne> TypeOne { get; set; }
    }
```

And here is the View:

```
<h1>My Projects</h1>
<hr />
<h4>Screening Forms</h4>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                State Project Number
            </th>
            <th>
                Federal Project Number
            </th>
            <th>
                Project Name
            </th>
            <th>
                County
            </th>
            <th>
                Coordinates
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model.Project_Screen)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.State_Project_Number)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Federal_Project_Number)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Project_Name)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.County)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Coordinates)
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.ID">Details</a> 
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>

<br />
<hr />

<h4>Type One Projects</h4>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                State Project Number
            </th>
            <th>
                Federal Project Number
            </th>
            <th>
                Project Name
            </th>
            <th>
                County
            </th>
            <th>
                Coordinates
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model.TypeOne)
        {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.State_Project_Number)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Federal_Project_Number)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.County)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Coordinates)
            </td>
            <td>
                <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.ID">Details</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Again, the issue is that `project_Screen` and `typeOne` aren't lists or IEnumerable types IN THE CONTROLLER. They are Lists in actuallity and everywhere EXCEPT the controller but they need to be. The error is on the lines

```
MyProjectsViewModel myProjectsViewModel = new MyProjectsViewModel()
            {
                Project_Screen = project_Screen,
                TypeOne = typeOne
            };
```

on `project_Screen` and `typeOne` and reads

```
cannot implicitly convert type Envapp.Models.DB.Project_Screen to System.Collection.Generic.List<Envapp.Models.DB.Project_Screen>
```

This appears to be happening because the code there is trying to point to the DB model table for Project_Screen rather than the ViewModel representation of items in the Project_Screen model. How do I fix this?

EDIT 2:

I'm not sure what it is but something in my code seems to be really confusing people. I am posting all of my models for clarification:

[image: File Structure]

Project_Screen.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

#nullable disable

namespace EnvApp.Models.DB
{
    public partial class Project_Screen
    {
        [Key]
        public long ID { get; set; }
        public string State_Project_Number { get; set; }
        public string? Federal_Project_Number { get; set; }
        public string Project_Name { get; set; }
        public string County { get; set; }
        public DateTime? Memo_Date { get; set; }
        public string From { get; set; }
        public string? Authorization { get; set; }
        public string DSN_PM { get; set; }
        public string? History { get; set; }
        public string History_PM { get; set; }
        public bool Review_Exempt_H { get; set; }
        public bool SHPO_Approval_H { get; set; }
        public string? Archaeology { get; set; }
        public string Archaeology_PM { get; set; }
        public bool Review_Exempt_A { get; set; }
        public bool SHPO_Approval_A { get; set; }
        public bool ESA_Key { get; set; }
        public bool Crayfish { get; set; }
        public bool Crayfish_Habitat_Assessment { get; set; }
        public bool NLEB_4D { get; set; }
        public bool USFWS { get; set; }
        public string USFWS_Type { get; set; }
        public bool Mussel_Habitat { get; set; }
        public bool Mussel_Stream { get; set; }
        public string Within_Airport { get; set; }
        public string? ToPo_Quad_Name { get; set; }
        public bool Bat_Habitat { get; set; }
        public string? Bars { get; set; }
        public string Coordinates { get; set; }
        public string? Natural_Resources_Notes { get; set; }
        public string Adduser { get; set; }
        public DateTime? Date_Added { get; set; }
        public string Crayfish_Notes { get; set; }
        public string Mussel_Notes { get; set; }

    }
}
```

TypeOne.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

#nullable disable

namespace EnvApp.Models.DB
{
    [Table("Type_One")]
    public partial class TypeOne
    {
        [Key]
        public long ID { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string State_Project_Number { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string Federal_Project_Number { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string Route_Number { get; set; }
        public string County { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string Work_Type { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(100)]
        public string Coordinates { get; set; }
        public string Project_Description { get; set; }
        public bool? Federal_Aid { get; set; }
        public bool? Minimal_Project_Verification { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(3)]
        public string CE_Category { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(10)]
        public string Amms { get; set; }
        public bool Activities_Agreement { get; set; }
        public string Arch_RE { get; set; }
        public string Hist_RE { get; set; }
        public DateTime? Arch_RE_Date { get; set; }
        public DateTime? Hist_RE_Date { get; set; }
        public bool? Through_Lanes { get; set; }
        public bool? Close_Road { get; set; }
        public bool? ROW_Acquisition { get; set; }
        public bool? Access_Control { get; set; }
        public bool? Fifty_Year_Structure { get; set; }
        public bool? Agency_Coordination { get; set; }
        public bool? IPAC_Screening_Zone { get; set; }
        public bool? Section_404_Permit { get; set; }
        public bool? Ground_Disturbance { get; set; }
        public bool? Waterway { get; set; }
        public bool? Special_Use_Permit { get; set; }
        public bool? Floodplain { get; set; }
        public string Prepared_By { get; set; }
        public string Approved_By { get; set; }
        public string Adduser { get; set; }
        public DateTime? Date_Added { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Natural_ResourcesContext

```
using System;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata;

#nullable disable

namespace EnvApp.Models.DB
{
    public partial class Natural_ResourcesContext : DbContext
    {
        public Natural_ResourcesContext()
        {
        }

        public Natural_ResourcesContext(DbContextOptions<Natural_ResourcesContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public virtual DbSet<NR_User> NR_Users { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Project_Screen> Project_Screen { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<TypeOne> TypeOne { get; set; }
        partial void OnModelCreatingPartial(ModelBuilder modelBuilder);
    } 
}
```

Comment: Why are you unboxing here? `Project_Screen project_Screen = (Project_Screen)(from s in...`. You cant unbox an enumerable type to a single type like that. Try removing `(Project_Screen)`.

Comment: I didn't know that. If I remove ````(Project_Screen)```` the query gets an error: ````Cannot implicitly convert type System.Link.IQueryable<Envapp.Models.DB.Project_Screen> to Envapp.Models.DB.Project_Screen. An explicit conversion exists.```` and that was the only suggestion so when I clicked add explicit conversion it did that and then the query worked.

How can I remedy this error the proper way?

Comment: Change your model property to: `public  IEnumerable<Project_Screen> Project_Screen { get; set; }`

Comment: That would break the project everywhere else that I use Project_Screen though... I'm going to post all my models because I think something is confusing people.

Comment: The second one. They are Edits of the same one.

Comment: See @hijinxbassist answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because you are using foreach on the view model itself, not on the properties you want to enumerate.

For Project_Screen and TypeOne, declare them as an enumerable type (eg. Array, List, IEnumerable, etc).

```
public class MyProjectsViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Project_Screen> Project_Screen { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<TypeOne> TypeOne { get; set; }
}
```

You will need to populate those with a collection of values from the controller

```
var viewModel = new MyProjectsViewModel();

viewModel.Project_Screen = _context.Project_Screen.Where(x => SOME_CONDITION);
viewModel.TypeOne = _context.TypeOne.Where(x => SOME_CONDITION);
```

In the view you will enumerate those properties (not the model itself).

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Project_Screen)
```

and

```
@foreach (var item in Model.TypeOne)
```

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to accept this answer, there were some problems in my code that made this confusing but once I figured it out this answer was really good. Thank you.

Comment: Glad my answer was helpful and that you solved your problem :)  Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

You were close enough. It seems your `Project_Screen` and `Type_One` should be list kind of class from your view iteration we got to know. If so, then your `MyProjectsViewModel` should be like:

***`View Model:`***

```
public class MyProjectsViewModel
    {
        public List<Project_Screen> ProjectScreen { get; set; }
        public List<Type_One>   TypeOne { get; set; }
    }
```

***`Controller:`***

```
 public ActionResult ViewModelEnumeration()
    {
        var proScreen = new List<Project_Screen>()
        {
            new Project_Screen(){ State_Project_Number = 1,Federal_Project_Number =1,Project_Name = "Project-1",  County = "USA"},
            new Project_Screen(){ State_Project_Number = 2,Federal_Project_Number =2,Project_Name = "Project-2",  County = "CA"},
            new Project_Screen(){ State_Project_Number = 3,Federal_Project_Number =3,Project_Name = "Project-3",  County = "UK"},
        };
        var typeOne = new List<Type_One>()
        {
            new Type_One(){ State_Project_Number = 101,Federal_Project_Number =101,Project_Name = "Type-One-Project-1",  County = "USA"},
            new Type_One(){ State_Project_Number = 102,Federal_Project_Number =102,Project_Name = "Type-One-Project-2",  County = "CA"},
            new Type_One(){ State_Project_Number = 103,Federal_Project_Number =103,Project_Name = "Type-One-Project-3",  County = "UK"},
        };
        //Bind to View Model
        MyProjectsViewModel viewModel = new MyProjectsViewModel();
        viewModel.ProjectScreen = proScreen;
        viewModel.TypeOne = typeOne;


        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

> ***Note:*** I am binding demo seeder property into the list. Feel free to change as per your requirement.Just getting you into the point.

***`View:`***

```
@model MVCApps.Models.MyProjectsViewModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "ViewModelEnumeration";
}

<h1>My Projects</h1>
<hr />
<h4>Screening Forms</h4>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                State Project Number
            </th>
            <th>
                Federal Project Number
            </th>
            <th>
                Project Name
            </th>
            <th>
                County
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model.ProjectScreen)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.State_Project_Number)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Federal_Project_Number)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Project_Name)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.County)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>

<br />
<hr />

<h4>Type One Projects</h4>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                State Project Number
            </th>
            <th>
                Federal Project Number
            </th>
            <th>
                Project Name
            </th>
            <th>
                County
            </th>
         
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model.TypeOne)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.State_Project_Number)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Federal_Project_Number)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Project_Name)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.County)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

***`Output:`***

[image]

> ***Note:*** So according to your scenario you can use like this `@foreach (var item in Model.Project_Screen)`. Additionally, be
> conscious about your naming convention like  `Project_Screen Project_Screen` is confusing either practice like  `Project_Screen ProjectScreen` or  `ProjectScreen Project_Screen`.

Hope above steps guide you accordingly. You can enhance your Idea more about this on our [official document here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-3)

***Update:***

> As per your comment I am also adding the example in case of single
> object means when you have other than `List` or `IEnumerable`

***`View Model:`***

```
 public class ProjectsScreenTypeOneViewModel
    {
        public Project_Screen ProjectScreen { get; set; }
        public Type_One TypeOne { get; set; }
    }
```

***`Controller:`***

```
public ActionResult ViewModelFromSingleObject()
        {
            //Binding Project_Screen Object
            var _proScreen = new Project_Screen();
            _proScreen.Project_Name = "Test Project-202";
            _proScreen.State_Project_Number = 1111;
            _proScreen.Federal_Project_Number = 11112021;
            _proScreen.County = "USA";

            //Binding Type_One Object
            var _typeOne = new Type_One();
            _typeOne.Project_Name = "Test Type One Project-101";
            _typeOne.State_Project_Number = 1010;
            _typeOne.Federal_Project_Number = 202121;
            _typeOne.County = "UK";
            //Binding to view model
            var _viewModel = new ProjectsScreenTypeOneViewModel();
            _viewModel.ProjectScreen = _proScreen;
            _viewModel.TypeOne = _typeOne;
            return View(_viewModel);
        }
```

***`View:`***

```
@model MVCApps.Models.ProjectsScreenTypeOneViewModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "ViewModelFromSingleObject";
}

<h2>ViewModelFromSingleObject</h2>

<h1>My Projects</h1>
<hr />
<h4>Screening Forms</h4>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                State Project Number
            </th>
            <th>
                Federal Project Number
            </th>
            <th>
                Project Name
            </th>
            <th>
                County
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.ProjectScreen.State_Project_Number)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.ProjectScreen.Federal_Project_Number)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.ProjectScreen.Project_Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.ProjectScreen.County)
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<br />
<hr />

<h4>Type One Projects</h4>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                State Project Number
            </th>
            <th>
                Federal Project Number
            </th>
            <th>
                Project Name
            </th>
            <th>
                County
            </th>

            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.TypeOne.State_Project_Number)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.TypeOne.Federal_Project_Number)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.TypeOne.Project_Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.TypeOne.County)
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

***`Output:`***

[image]

> ***`Note:`*** Now as you can see I have added both `single` and `List` kind of example which will guided you accordingly. If you still
> encounter any further issue feel free to share.

Comment: I love this answer, thank you so much for your time. I'm still just a bit confused on my controller though. I've updated my question for a more in depth explanation, but basically the issue is that ````project_Screen```` and ````typeOne```` aren't lists or IEnumerable types, which makes sense, but I'm not the syntax to get them to be enumerable.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In case of single object other than `List` or `Enumerable` you can try my updated answer.

Comment: Hello @GrillOwner69420 do you need any further asistance on this?

Comment: Hey @Md Farid Uddin Kiron sorry I went on a vacation. Yes, it seems I didn't do a good job explaining the problem. Take a look at my updated question please; I believe I've clarified things.

Comment: I got it figured out with the other answer on this post. Thank you so much for taking the time to help me I really appreciate it,